# How to set max peers per room in socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

thanks for willing to help.

Here is my problem : I want to make a room for max 2 peers in socket.io , and this is my code which is supposed to work but it doesn't

```
 if(isEmpty(io.sockets.manager.rooms)){
        for(var val in io.sockets.manager.rooms){
            if(io.sockets.clients(val) < 2 ){
                user.room = val;

            }
            else if (io.sockets.clients(val) === 2 ) pass;
            else {
                user.room = socket.id;

            }
        }        
    }
    else{
        user.room = socket.id;
        console.log(user);
    }
    socket.join(user.room);
}
function isEmpty(object)
{
  var isEmpty = true;
  if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object).length > 0) isEmpty = false;
   return isEmpty;
}
```

So basically I want it to check if there is no room yet , create it with a name of socket.id , if there is(are) room(s) , put the socket in a room where is 0 or 1 socket. But the script isn't working properly , which is why i am here, it creates a room for each socket.

Comment: fix your syntax errors and repost, then we can help...

Comment: pass isn't a Javascript keyword. Try using `io.sockets.clients(val) > 2`, remove `pass;` and remove the line with `else {`